# Change content's default language in MacOS TV app

Tags: catalina, settings, appletv

I'm trying to find a way to set English (my system language is French) as the default audio language for Apple TV+ content.

On an Apple TV you can set that in the system's settings.

On MacOS, you can change the language from the player itself but it will not be remembered for the next episode. I can't find anything in the app's preference nor in the system's settings.

**How do I change the default playback language for the Apple TV app on MacOS ?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I also had this problem with my German macOS. I found the solution: you can set the language of each Mac app separately.

1. Go to your macOS Settings -> Language & Region
2. Go to tab "Apps"
3. Click on "+" and add the "TV" app with language set to English

Now English is the default audio language for everything you play in the Apple TV app.